# Función jQuery para mandarme hacia arriba de la pantalla

Tags: jquery

Tengo una serie de `inputs` tipo `radio` y quiero que al pinchar en ellos me mande hacia arriba de la pantalla con una función `jQuery`.
¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Tengo esta función y no me hace nada.

```
$("input[name='piezas']").click(function () {
    $(html).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que la respuesta anterior es mucho más detallada, pero ciñéndome a tu problema, si lo único que quieres es hacer scroll hacia arriba, prueba poner:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

El primer 0 es la posición X y el segundo la posición Y.
Además es una función nativa de Javascript, no necesitas jQuery

Un saludo!

Answer (score 7):

Te mando un ejemplo y además te lo explico.

Primero insertamos el enlace del botón.

```
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
```

◾Ahora le añadimos el estilo al botón.

```
.scrollup{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    opacity:0.3;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    right:100px;
    display:none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Hemos definido la posición del botón como fija con 100px a la derecha y 50px del pie de la página. Hemos usado la propiedad “text-ident” para esconder el texto y mostrar el icono del botón. La propiedad “display:none;” hace que el botón sea invisible al principio.

El icono para el botón ‘icon_top.png‘ es el siguiente:

icon_top

◾Ahora queremos que el botón sea visible si navegamos hacia abajo. Esto lo podemos hacer con el evento scroll de jQuery.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
   } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
   }
});
```

La propiedad scrollTop obtiene la posición vertical actual de la barra de desplazamiento (barra de scroll). Si es superior a 100px, muestra el botón para ir arriba, si es inferior a 100px lo oculta.

◾El siguiente paso es hacer la animación para ir arriba de la página web al pulsar el botón.

```
$('.scrollup').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

La propiedad scrollTop:0 nos desplaza hacia el comienzo de la página web, en la posición 0px, y 600 representa la duración de la animación en milisegundos. Un valor más alto significa una animación más lenta. También puedes usar las propiedades predefinidas como ‘fast‘, ‘slow‘ o ‘normal‘ en vez de usar los milisegundos.

◾Este es el código jQuery completo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $('.scrollup').click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: gracias.....amigo, si hay otras formas me dices porfa seria bueno aprender distintas formas

Comment: una pregunta que pasa si el scroll no es del window y es del modals; en este caso como se haria ???

Comment: hola amigos tienen una idea ?

Comment: porfa respondan :-<