# ¿Como puedo hacer que la pantalla suba automaticamente con js? subiendo el scroll 300px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buenos dias;

Tengo unos cuantos elementos puestos en un div, pero necesito que si se da click sobre alguno suba el scroll suba automaticamnte hasta la parte superior de la pantalla, pero no encuentra una funcion o alguna forma de lograr este cometido.

¿Alguna idea?, Gracias.

Comment: [Este otro post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64158/funci%C3%B3n-jquery-para-mandarme-hac%C3%ADa-arriba-de-la-pantalla) te puede ayudar.

Comment: @ElChiniNet no es un duplicado de la primera, es relacionada, pero si es duplicada de la que relacionas. saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te dejo un ejemplo de jQuery para modificar el scroll:

```js
  $("div.demo").scrollTop(300);
```

```css
div.demo {
  background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollTop demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="demo">
    <h1>lalala</h1>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>



</body>
```

Comment: Gracias... Me ayudaste mucho con esta linea... Te agradezco 
`$("div.demo").scrollTop(300);`

Answer (score 1):

En realidad si lo único que quieres es ir al principio de la página al pulsar un elemento ni siquiera necesitas utilizar javascript. Con un link con href="#top" te bastaría:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In venenatis iaculis lacinia. Nullam at eros sollicitudin, rutrum mi vel, facilisis felis. Nulla sit amet commodo augue. Suspendisse cursus nisl lectus, sit amet sodales quam blandit et. Nam consectetur dictum dapibus. Quisque ac tortor neque. Mauris sed sem augue. Phasellus feugiat sapien eget arcu congue tincidunt. Aenean nec justo in neque gravida rutrum condimentum vitae eros. Nulla facilisis dolor nisi, nec posuere justo pharetra sit amet. Nam ultricies mollis augue a egestas. Morbi quis dignissim ipsum. Nam feugiat neque nunc. Vestibulum porttitor ligula eu augue varius, vel ullamcorper augue imperdiet. Nam aliquet, nibh at sollicitudin efficitur, lectus arcu suscipit arcu, eget hendrerit augue nulla vitae turpis.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec dolor purus, commodo in libero nec, placerat vestibulum erat. Vivamus efficitur lectus libero, ac convallis mauris condimentum nec. Etiam ante magna, hendrerit a justo in, lacinia egestas metus. Nullam iaculis rutrum viverra. Donec a ligula a ipsum ultrices convallis eget maximus lorem. Proin aliquam mauris sed sapien luctus condimentum. Vivamus id tellus quis augue semper tempus vitae at dolor. Nullam tempus sed sapien eu tempor. Praesent dictum et dui ac ullamcorper. Ut gravida tellus ac scelerisque volutpat. Donec sagittis urna nec fermentum vulputate. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum a diam vel felis sagittis scelerisque. Vestibulum facilisis tincidunt dui nec fringilla. Quisque commodo urna ante, quis dapibus leo rhoncus sit amet.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Suspendisse vel massa vitae quam varius facilisis et tincidunt enim. Sed mollis sit amet velit eget congue. Sed metus lacus, lobortis vitae auctor sed, pellentesque sit amet nulla. Nam convallis, mauris et fringilla porttitor, ipsum turpis malesuada elit, eget ultricies ligula nunc at lectus. Vivamus pretium vitae sem eget ornare. Phasellus condimentum hendrerit lobortis. Aenean blandit ullamcorper arcu, in sodales dui auctor vitae. Proin suscipit enim a metus maximus scelerisque. Nunc at velit suscipit, tincidunt ex id, porta purus. Proin vulputate, ligula ut ultricies porta, orci sapien consequat nibh, vitae porta diam mauris ac felis. Maecenas cursus turpis feugiat, vehicula nunc ut, laoreet orci. Maecenas pellentesque, nisi nec congue tristique, ligula mauris tempor est, eu dignissim purus nisl non libero. Pellentesque in facilisis enim. Morbi dui felis, venenatis in quam in, lobortis accumsan metus. Praesent in dolor ac enim auctor ultrices. Aliquam sed hendrerit nulla.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris accumsan malesuada dolor non aliquet. Vestibulum ac magna fermentum, volutpat sapien sodales, pulvinar lorem. Maecenas ac urna nibh. Vivamus quis lacus vel mauris feugiat auctor viverra vel elit. Aliquam tristique massa lacus, quis accumsan purus pulvinar eget. Proin eu vulputate augue.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Donec a suscipit ipsum. Vivamus at enim tempor justo feugiat sollicitudin. Pellentesque at tortor id magna auctor scelerisque. Maecenas iaculis rutrum cursus. Maecenas rhoncus leo vitae tempor facilisis. Nullam ac dolor in turpis viverra tincidunt vel eu ex. Proin interdum, tortor et malesuada laoreet, purus nisl lacinia magna, feugiat fermentum diam est ornare ligula. Donec in ligula quis mauris congue convallis quis sed metus. Pellentesque lacinia ut quam nec tincidunt. Curabitur tincidunt id dolor ut varius. Vestibulum elementum diam a ipsum pulvinar feugiat. In quis pulvinar nisi.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>In tortor mauris, tristique vel blandit et, finibus sed risus. Sed finibus luctus ipsum, sit amet efficitur elit viverra eu. Nam sit amet nunc finibus, cursus est vitae, aliquam eros. Cras non mauris ornare, imperdiet nisi et, molestie risus. Aliquam risus tortor, laoreet sit amet dictum a, posuere vitae turpis. In tristique, eros et gravida maximus, tortor mauris laoreet turpis, in lacinia metus odio vulputate felis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce faucibus a risus et porta. Sed nec est et orci sollicitudin ultrices. Nulla a venenatis ipsum, nec semper nisi. Duis suscipit vulputate mollis. Praesent velit metus, varius a tristique nec, feugiat ac sapien. Nulla tincidunt vulputate tellus, non pretium metus venenatis vel. Nunc nec dui feugiat, eleifend justo eu, dapibus nulla. Pellentesque pellentesque cursus dictum.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Aenean lobortis mauris et sapien maximus, nec cursus ipsum pulvinar. Fusce sit amet dui eget nibh facilisis ullamcorper at vel ante. Maecenas ut commodo massa. Pellentesque ut nibh semper, tincidunt orci at, convallis tellus. Integer elit risus, aliquet quis leo non, porta dictum mauris. Ut pulvinar felis ac lectus malesuada, et convallis nisl interdum. Morbi malesuada leo risus, vel maximus felis ultrices in. Curabitur suscipit orci in porta scelerisque. Maecenas ut posuere nunc, at tincidunt quam. Donec et libero nibh. Integer pulvinar ipsum ac orci pretium mollis.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Aenean nec laoreet ipsum. Nulla molestie rutrum sem vitae imperdiet. Etiam a tellus sit amet ex facilisis consectetur. Integer scelerisque maximus odio quis semper. Suspendisse sed luctus augue. Duis scelerisque sit amet purus sed pellentesque. In orci sem, ornare vel nisi vel, efficitur viverra elit. Aliquam enim velit, lacinia in euismod vel, posuere ut tortor. Donec sed accumsan sem. Pellentesque in elit id augue porttitor imperdiet sed vehicula risus. Donec at lobortis enim. Pellentesque tempor finibus odio, sit amet aliquet nunc pharetra a. Sed tortor tellus, lobortis non egestas ut, auctor sed metus. Pellentesque dignissim dolor in lectus placerat molestie. In in elementum elit.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Aliquam tempor ex porttitor tincidunt scelerisque. Cras imperdiet aliquet tortor, id finibus dolor malesuada quis. Curabitur sed erat dapibus, hendrerit mi id, aliquam lacus. Nulla sollicitudin fermentum velit, id aliquam eros finibus quis. Cras id leo lobortis, rhoncus magna sit amet, lacinia diam. Donec ullamcorper rutrum mi vitae dapibus. Nam nec malesuada magna, eget viverra est. Integer molestie metus in dolor commodo accumsan. Mauris maximus neque quis mauris pulvinar, et tempus purus sagittis.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Sed bibendum in leo id ultrices. Maecenas convallis, diam feugiat vehicula pulvinar, metus nisl mollis leo, ut tempor urna ante posuere nisl. Donec sed odio vel diam tempor pulvinar ut a urna. Praesent sem tortor, aliquet nec libero cursus, finibus tempus dolor. Duis pellentesque ac libero mattis rutrum. Maecenas a blandit lectus, ac egestas nulla. Cras ullamcorper diam at purus posuere rhoncus. Donec vel leo bibendum, facilisis odio quis, bibendum enim. Pellentesque commodo elit sit amet libero consectetur posuere. Donec porttitor, lacus vitae ornare bibendum, risus massa aliquam leo, non vulputate mauris purus sit amet diam.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Ut bibendum finibus facilisis. In interdum neque ut ipsum finibus vehicula. Duis eu gravida elit. Ut bibendum non nulla sed lobortis. Nunc ut est urna. Nunc aliquet dolor augue, sit amet venenatis tortor aliquam quis. Quisque viverra scelerisque felis id tristique. Mauris dictum, nisi ut dapibus sollicitudin, lorem mi vestibulum risus, ac eleifend dui enim eget tellus. Sed auctor dictum sem, eu faucibus leo pretium vel. Pellentesque bibendum placerat orci, et convallis libero rutrum nec. Maecenas ut felis eget purus congue rutrum vel eget magna. Ut congue sollicitudin diam ut lobortis. Mauris vel nunc tempor, molestie justo sed, sagittis risus. Ut erat augue, mollis sit amet tempor et, mattis eu libero. Maecenas fringilla odio tortor, id sagittis enim lobortis at. Vivamus sit amet porta leo, id cursus ex.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Donec ac congue quam, eu lobortis mauris. Curabitur gravida vehicula enim sit amet ultricies. Praesent pellentesque elementum enim, ac mattis mauris suscipit sed. Ut varius accumsan massa, vehicula commodo felis gravida nec. Ut fermentum odio orci, nec lacinia sem tristique eu. Aliquam fringilla sollicitudin tellus. Curabitur eu pellentesque nibh.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Sed vulputate ullamcorper ipsum. Integer sed euismod lectus, a pulvinar lorem. Ut nisl arcu, gravida in egestas eget, commodo et purus. Sed suscipit bibendum leo sed rutrum. Donec hendrerit arcu urna, vel finibus nisi suscipit eget. Morbi condimentum accumsan felis. Proin vitae lacus nulla. Aliquam consequat maximus rhoncus.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Morbi faucibus aliquet pulvinar. Nunc suscipit dolor metus, ut bibendum magna gravida ut. Proin sit amet est scelerisque tortor eleifend feugiat nec non turpis. Ut at leo ultrices, bibendum orci id, pellentesque odio. Morbi mattis auctor arcu, eu vulputate quam dignissim et. Phasellus tincidunt metus eget nulla rutrum, vel congue lacus convallis. Proin iaculis feugiat pretium. Aenean vel eros accumsan ligula hendrerit hendrerit sed eu ligula. In laoreet gravida ligula, et semper ipsum aliquet vel. Suspendisse tincidunt eleifend sodales. Fusce non cursus turpis. Aenean in tincidunt tellus. Integer dictum leo dictum mauris tincidunt, et lobortis quam interdum. Pellentesque non efficitur diam, nec consectetur orci. Nam tincidunt risus libero, at pellentesque ex fermentum sit amet. Nullam sodales egestas lacinia.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Nam in lorem dui. Sed semper nec arcu sit amet pharetra. Integer vulputate ex non risus tempor convallis. Donec massa libero, molestie nec finibus quis, tristique et eros. Praesent fermentum quam velit, et elementum risus gravida et. Cras consectetur velit nisl, a malesuada metus convallis quis. Sed dui mi, bibendum nec sem sed, porttitor malesuada dui. Maecenas tristique mauris nec est aliquet varius. Ut ornare fringilla augue sed rutrum. Nullam dapibus, odio quis commodo vestibulum, tellus dui ullamcorper nisl, et vulputate mi dolor vitae orci. Morbi ac erat scelerisque, porttitor ipsum sed, aliquet arcu. Donec lobortis orci et auctor luctus. In aliquam nulla vestibulum leo molestie, id sollicitudin mauris condimentum. Nunc ante nibh, imperdiet vel porttitor in, imperdiet at nisi. Etiam tempor malesuada nisl, ut pellentesque ligula lacinia a.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Donec sit amet molestie velit. Phasellus justo erat, blandit eget neque ultrices, efficitur commodo metus. Nullam ut massa mauris. Nulla sodales, tellus feugiat volutpat scelerisque, eros tellus dignissim magna, vitae congue diam orci vitae urna. Ut at feugiat purus. Fusce viverra tincidunt diam, sed posuere orci viverra in. Vivamus id cursus elit, vitae faucibus quam.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Nunc auctor eleifend orci et euismod. Nunc rutrum imperdiet lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ac justo ut velit aliquet vehicula. Integer ut vestibulum nisi, eu porttitor orci. Sed pellentesque laoreet tortor, ut condimentum augue. Vivamus neque nunc, elementum et placerat vel, vulputate at tortor. Pellentesque fermentum venenatis massa. Integer consequat felis id porta interdum. Quisque gravida sollicitudin blandit. Donec rutrum neque sit amet augue molestie dignissim. Sed tincidunt placerat convallis. Praesent id odio ut diam bibendum pellentesque in vel ligula.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Aenean efficitur ligula lacus, in sagittis justo viverra nec. Sed pharetra lobortis dolor at congue. Aliquam sit amet leo semper mauris suscipit hendrerit. Sed vel elit id sapien sollicitudin viverra. Sed volutpat et ligula nec sodales. Curabitur id est auctor, auctor nunc rutrum, lobortis urna. Donec vestibulum dolor vitae dignissim sollicitudin. Donec et metus ligula. Fusce convallis eu augue nec pretium. Vestibulum pulvinar maximus risus a vulputate. Fusce at ante nec nisl pellentesque tristique in ut nisi. Proin eu metus consectetur, finibus felis eu, dignissim velit. Curabitur aliquam orci a neque ultrices suscipit.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>Maecenas ultricies eros vel malesuada posuere. Nam pharetra bibendum urna, sed tempus ex tristique condimentum. Vestibulum porttitor lectus quis libero dignissim dignissim. Cras facilisis fermentum libero, ac convallis sapien cursus eu. Nam placerat nunc et neque congue, vel semper nibh mattis. Maecenas ultrices consequat ligula, ut volutpat velit vehicula a. Fusce scelerisque enim vel ex accumsan, sit amet ullamcorper mauris rhoncus.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>

<p>In mollis varius vehicula. Phasellus id iaculis dolor. Morbi rhoncus nisi ligula, id faucibus lorem faucibus ac. Duis posuere semper justo, a vehicula erat tempor a. Suspendisse vitae est tempor, blandit mauris sit amet, pellentesque enim. In condimentum, libero id sollicitudin feugiat, felis ipsum scelerisque felis, eu commodo est leo id ante. Sed elementum dui quis rutrum tristique. Morbi feugiat est in neque semper, a venenatis nunc egestas. Ut congue mi urna, non sodales tortor pulvinar quis. Quisque ut ante suscipit, dictum nisi rhoncus, aliquet ligula. Mauris ullamcorper tincidunt felis, ac porta magna varius in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi fermentum lorem sit amet tellus tincidunt, vitae luctus lectus tempus. Cras a augue vitae urna luctus venenatis.</p>
<a href="#top">Arriba</a>
```